# Importing library Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, production, angular-library

I have a problem that i don't know how to resolve.

Im trying to make from my application a library to use it in different project. In my library im using a few libraries like material,forms etc. When i'm connected from different project into my library which working like API i don't see the CSS style, rest is working fine like scripts etc.
Im using angular 15.2.9 and later i want to pack this into tgz file but now this don't want to work. Any ideas?

I added to my css file in my lib the import css like that "@import "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";" then im getting error in the console on site about
"Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4202/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled." , i added the peerDependencies which doesn't work. The angular versions are the same.